# How to keep the orientation of indices vector while array indexing (instead of the orientation of indexed vector)

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I have an assignment like `C = A(B)` in a loop that size and shape of `B` change in every iteration. I need the size of `C` to be exactly like `B`. Documentation describes [array indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) like this:

> If you index into a vector with another vector, the orientation of the **indexed vector** is honored for the output
>
> If you index into a vector with a nonvector, the shape of the **indices** is honored

So how can I keep shape and orientation of *indices* in both cases?

Comment: That's annoying sometimes, isn't it? A solution is to apply `C = reshape(C, size(B));` afterwards

Comment: @LuisMendo It really is. Are there any other options? I need it to be as fast as possible, since `A` and `B` are both relatively large and for-loop may cycle more than 100K times...

Comment: Quite probably, that `reshape` [will not increase](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36062574/2586922) running time significantly